# How to rotate a table 45 degrees and save the result into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, matrix

I have a table.

```
---------
| a | b |
---------
| a | b |
---------
```

I want to rotate it 45 degrees(clockwise or anti-clockwise) and save it into another table. For example, if I rotate it 45 degrees anti-clockwise, it will be:

```
-------------
| b |   |   |
-------------
| a | b |   |
-------------
| a |   |   |
-------------
```

Another example, when I rotate

```
-------------
| a | b | c |
-------------
| d | e | f |
-------------
| g | h | i |
-------------
```

It will change to

```
---------------------
| c |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
| b | f |   |   |   |
---------------------
| a | e | i |   |   |
---------------------
| d | h |   |   |   |
---------------------
| g |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
```

How to do this in `SQL`?

Comment: @Richard
I'm using SQL Server 2005 or 2008.

Comment: May I know what is the purpose of rotating the table values to 45 degrees?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A fully working example (for SQL Server 2005+)
If you need it for another system, there are equivalents for the pieces of the puzzle below

- row_number()
- dense_rank()
- un/pivot

You can find the equivalents from other Stackoverflow questions. For example, the first two are well supported by Oracle and DB2.

```
create table t45 (id int identity, colA char(1), colX char(1), colZ char(1))
insert t45 select 'a','b','c'
insert t45 select 'd','e','f'
insert t45 select 'g','h','i'
GO

select [1],[2],[3],[4],[5] -- for N columns, this goes to N*2-1
from
(
    select value,
        targetRow = row+col-1,
        targetCol = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by row+col-1 order by row)
    from
    (
        select *,
            row = DENSE_RANK() over (order by id),
            col = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by
                CASE source when 'colA' then 3 -- number in reverse
                            when 'colX' then 2
                            when 'colZ' then 1 end)
        from t45
        unpivot (value for source in (colA,colX,colZ)) upv
    ) x
) p                                -- for N columns, this goes to N*2-1
pivot (max(value) for targetCol in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) pv
order by targetRow
```

If you need to arbitrarily apply it to any table - use dynamic SQL to generate the pattern shown above.

Comment: Thanks Richard, you are really a SQL Guru!

Comment: This is one of the smartest things i've seen on SO. Even for purely theoretical value, i would like to see this in a blog explained and generalized for multiples of 45 degrees. Brilliant Richard. Sorry if i sound like a fan boy, but i am really amazed by this:)

Comment: To get ypercube's output, change `targetCol = ROW_NUMBER()..` to `targetCol = ABS(3 - (row+col-1))-1+2*ROW_NUMBER()..` I'll add more comments if inspiration avails to expand on the answer

Comment: This is ridiculous and amazing.

Comment: Checking someone's profile when discussing some issues can be enlightening, sometimes great things are found. Dude, this piece of code is amazing. I wonder if @Yousui finally got done his SQL chess game, it would be great to take a look and learn from it.

Comment: A magnificent answer, its upvotes only limited by the fact that no sane person on earth would actually want to do this :)

Answer (score 9):

Shouldn't the table

```
---------
| a | b |
---------
| a | b |
---------
```

rotated 45 degrees anti-clockwise be like this?

```
-------------
|   | b |   |
-------------
| a |   | b |
-------------
|   | a |   |
-------------
```

and the

```
-------------
| a | b | c |
-------------
| d | e | f |
-------------
| g | h | i |
-------------
```

something like:

```
---------------------
|   |   | c |   |   |
---------------------
|   | b |   | f |   |
---------------------
| a |   | e |   | i |
---------------------
|   | d |   | h |   |
---------------------
|   |   | g |   |   |
---------------------
```

Comment: No, but I couldn't paste these tables inside a comment. We deserve a clear description of the problem before trying to answer, don't we?

Comment: ypercube - one more step (flush to left) and you will have the question structure

Comment: @Richard: I see the light now, thnx!

Comment: But this way (as suggested by OP) leaves the problem that rotating 8 times by 45 degrees, will not get you back to the original position (table).

Comment: yeah, the term "rotation" was ill-chosen

Comment: You can explain it in your question above separating by `<hr>`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way of doing this directly in SQL.

I suggest you import the result into a different programming environment, such as Java, PHP, Python or what ever, solve the problem in this context, and then (if necessary) put the result back into the DB.

Comment: Whoosh... the sound of the point of all of this flying over someone's head at high speed. It's the same reason people do stuff like [this](https://www.ioccc.org/)!

Answer (score 1):

Option for SQLServer2008+ with CROSS APPLY and PIVOT operators

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test77
 (
  id int IDENTITY, 
  colA char(1), 
  colB char(1), 
  colC char(1)
  )

INSERT dbo.test77
VALUES('a','b','c'),
      ('d','e','f'),
      ('g','h','i')

SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM (
      SELECT COALESCE(o.colA, o.colB, o.colC) AS Val,
             'Col' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS nvarchar(1)) AS ColName 
      FROM dbo.test77 t CROSS APPLY (
                                     VALUES(colA, NULL, NULL),
                                           (NULL, colB, NULL),
                                           (NULL, NULL, colC)
                                     ) o(colA, colB, colC)
      ) p
PIVOT (
MAX(Val) FOR ColName IN ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4], [Col5], [Col6], [Col7], [Col8], [Col9])
) pvt CROSS APPLY (
                   VALUES ([Col3], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
                          ([Col2], [Col6], NULL, NULL, NULL),
                          ([Col1], [Col5], [Col9], NULL, NULL),
                          ([Col4], [Col8], NULL, NULL, NULL),
                          ([Col7], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
                   ) o([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3aedf/1)